# App Bar Layout Not Working

Tags: android, toolbar

### [image: Material Design]

I am trying to achieve this.

---

[image: My app]

This i what i have achieved so far.

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cor_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/primaryColor"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                android:theme="@style/MyCustomToolbarTheme"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:rippleColor="?attr/colorControlHighlight" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The problem is no matter how many items i add to the recycler view the app bar layout does not scroll,it just stays pinned.I know the image has not been added but that's okay for now.Could someone tell me what is missing here and why it is not scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapseToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="80dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="30dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="Custom Layout">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/bridge"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.5"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        app:elevation="10dp"
        android:translationZ="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/plus" />
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/uid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In your activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapse;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        floatingActionButton=(FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        collapse=(CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapseToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        collapse.setTitle("Title");
        collapse.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        collapse.setExpandedTitleColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        collapse.setStatusBarScrimColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Comment: Thank you that worked.Could you tell me what i had done wrong and also you have set the visibility of the fab to gone but it still shows up anchored to the appbar,how does that work?

Comment: Is it possible to set the image view contained inside programmatically in the app?

Comment: yes it is possible, you can get the id and set image asap

Comment: also remove the visibility gone thing, i had implemented this earlier so i didn't notice

Comment: also please mark my answer as correct if it helped you, thanks

Comment: I gave the image an id and used find view by id to get it in the activity but using set image does not work.Neither does it work when i try to set the title of the collapsing toolbar layout based on user input.

Comment: i have edited my code, hope this much code would be enough, also which method are you using to set image, please explain.

Comment: Thank you for the code,i am giving the user an option to select an image from the gallery and then set that image to the image view inside the collapsing toolbar,i have successfully got the uri of the image but imageView.setImageUri(path) doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90361/discussion-between-aakash-and-jude-fernandes).